# Resizable image thumbnails in Microsoft Word (or other Microsoft Office suite programs)?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

Eg. an image thumbnail that you can click to view a full-size version of the image and then click again to return it to thumbnail form.

Is this possible? I couldn't figure out how to do it. My goal is to document a set of screens for an application and the transitions between them, but full size images would not work well at all due to the amount of space they would consume and just thumbnails would provide insufficient detail for each screen.

I'm also open to any alternative ways of approaching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft word intended as a word processor for the most part.  It is aimed at the creation of documents which can ultimately be printed or saved out as PDF files.  This sort of functionality while theoretically possible by the use of a lot of VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) code isn't something word would handle well.

If you are wanting to accomplish through the use of a Microsoft Office product, I would recommend trying powerpoint.

Add your image at thumbnail in the slide you want to animate, select the "Add Animation" button and pick Grow/Shrink:
[image]

Select "Trigger" and pick "on click of (image)":
[image]

Next, edit the effect options and change the size to be something huge (300% or more maybe?):
[image]
[image]

Now, when in your slideshow - when you click the small icon, it will grow.

You can also add other transitions too and daisy chain them.  You can add additional transitions to hide the images again after a delay, move around the page, fade in and out etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't attached to using Microsoft Word specifically. I tried poking around in PowerPoint but had not thought of using animations. This should do the trick for what I was trying to accomplish, thank you!

Comment: you're very welcome.  If this has helped you, please upvote and/or accept this answer so that it can help others in a similar situation too.